# I'm attempting to represent a sql join in a flask application using SQLAlchemy as db.session

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

```
apInfo = db.engine.execute(
    "select L.circuit_id, L.remote_id, AP_I.vlan, AP_I.color \
     from leases as L, ap_info as AP_I \
     where L.circuit_id = AP_I.mac_address and \
           L.remote_id = '%s'; " % sm_mac_.remote_id[:17]).fetchone()
```

This generates correctly:
 (u'0a:00:3e:bb:76:54             ', u'0a:00:3e:bb:c1:f7             ', 12, 77))

My attempt at representation as:

```
apInfo = db.session.query(LEASES, AP_INFO) \
    .filter(LEASES.circuit_id == AP_INFO.mac_address)\
    .filter(LEASES.remote_id == sm_mac_.remote_id[:17])\
    .all ()
```

Produces a list containing a tuple?;
     [(<**main**.LEASES object at 0x101f039d0>, <**main**.AP_INFO object at 0x101f0e410>)]

Trying to determine how to modify the db.session or extract the data from what is has produced.

Comment: Are you just asking why your second example returns the result(s) in a list?

Answer (score 0):

This works but is not done!

```
ret = db.session.query(LEASES, AP_INFO) \
             .filter(LEASES.circuit_id == AP_INFO.mac_address)\
             .filter(LEASES.remote_id == sm_mac_.remote_id[:17])\
             .all ()

apInfo = (ret[0].LEASES.circuit_id, \
   ret[0].LEASES.remote_id, \
   ret[0].AP_INFO.vlan, \
   ret[0].AP_INFO.color)
```

I'd like to find a way to directly return the values from the query; to improve the query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to use `.one()` instead of `.all()`:

```
apInfo = db.session.query(LEASES, AP_INFO) \
    .filter(LEASES.circuit_id == AP_INFO.mac_address)\
    .filter(LEASES.remote_id == sm_mac_.remote_id[:17])\
    .one()
```

---

Your first example using an [`Engine`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) returns a [`ResultProxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy), which you then use to call [`ResultProxy.fetchone()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.fetchone).

However, your second example using [`db.Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) uses [`Query.all()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all), which *always* returns results wrapped in a list:

> ```
> all()
>
>     Return the results represented by this Query as a list.
> ```

If you know you are only expecting a single result, use [`Query.one()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) or [`Query.one_or_none`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) instead.

Alternatively, if your query may return multiple results but you only want the first, there's [`Query.first()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first)